# Riverpod StateNotifier with singleton class

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod

Two days of experimentation to solve the puzzle of not listening for any changes of the singleton  properties, when working with  multi instance classes, it works fine. Is this a problem in the package it self or is it normal?

Is there any way or workaround for this problem?

**Singleton class code:**

```
class Connection extends SocketConnection {
  static final Connection _instance = Connection._internal();

  ClientState clientstate = ClientState.disconnected;
  
  factory Connection() {
    return _instance;
  }

  Connection._internal() {
    debugPrint("XXX Connection Created.");
  }
}
```

**StateNotifier And Provider code:**

```
class ClientStateNotifier extends StateNotifier<Connection> {
  ClientStateNotifier() : super(Connection());
  // late Timer _timer;

  void changeConnectiontState() {
    if (state.clientstate == ClientState.connecting) {
      state = Connection()..clientstate = ClientState.disconnected;
      return;
    }
    state = Connection()..clientstate = ClientState.connecting;
  }
}

final connectionProvider =
    StateNotifierProvider<ClientStateNotifier, Connection>(
        (ref) => ClientStateNotifier());
```

**Screen code:**

```
class HomeBody extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  const HomeBody({super.key});

  @override
  ConsumerState<HomeBody> createState() => _HomeBodyState();
}

class _HomeBodyState extends ConsumerState<HomeBody> {


  void changeClientState() {
    ref.read(connectionProvider.notifier).changeConnectiontState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final connection = ref.watch(connectionProvider);

   

    return SafeArea(
        child: Column(
      children: [
        Text(connection.clientstate.toString()),
          CircleButton(
                icon: Icons.arrow_circle_right_outlined,
                onPress: () {
                  changeClientState();
                },
              ),
          ],
    ));
  }
}
```

riverpod with singleton class not works as expected.

Comment: Please stop using StateNotifier... The literature is rushing to catch up with Remi's prolific development.  In brief, avoid legacy ChangeNotifier, StateNotifier (and their providers) and StateProvider.  Use only Provider, FutureProvider, StreamProvider, and Notifier, AsyncNotifier, StreamNotifier (and their providers).

Comment: @RandalSchwartz  I'm new with riverpod, so I will use suggested providers. thank you

Answer (score 1):

Your `state` for `StateNotifier` must be an immutable object (`clientstate` must be `final`). That's not the case now at all.

If `Connection` still cannot be made immutable consider using `ChangeNotifierProvider` - there it is sufficient to call the `notifyListeners` method to notify listeners when needed.

Comment: I saw that using ChangeNotifierProvider  make the entire screen rebuilds its same as setState case, is there is solution to listen to provider changes without screen rebuilds every time.

Comment: Yes, you can try to use `ref.watch(provider.select(...))`